# Separating a string using predefined characters

Tags: python, regex, split

I have a text as `Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada. I have 2 pets. One is a dog and the other is a Zebra. Ahoi! Thanks.`

I want to split this sentence from `.` and '!', how can i do this. I also want to know from what character the sentence split.

For example the result should be:

Example 1:

`Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada || The sentence was split with .`

Example 2:

`Ahoi! || The sentence was split with !`

How can i do this? My working so far:

`print (text.split('.'))` - This only breaks the sentence with the `.`, and i have no way to determine what character it used to split.

Comment: Is the question to know which character was used to split or how to split the sentence?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `re.split()`:

```
re.split('[.!]', text)
```

This splits on any of the characters in the `[...]` character class:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada. I have 2 pets. One is a dog and the other is a Zebra. Ahoi! Thanks.'
>>> re.split('[.!]', text)
['Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada', ' I have 2 pets', ' One is a dog and the other is a Zebra', ' Ahoi', ' Thanks', '']
```

You can group the split expression to include the characters in separate list elements in the output:

```
>>> re.split('([.!])', text)
['Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada', '.', ' I have 2 pets', '.', ' One is a dog and the other is a Zebra', '.', ' Ahoi', '!', ' Thanks', '.', '']
```

To keep the punctuation attached to the sentence, use `re.findall()` instead:

```
>>> re.findall('[^.!]+?[.!]', text)
['Hi, my name is Will, And i am from Canada.', ' I have 2 pets.', ' One is a dog and the other is a Zebra.', ' Ahoi!', ' Thanks.']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> sp=re.split('(\.)|(!)','aaa.bbb!ccc!ddd.eee')
>>> sp
['aaa', '.', None, 'bbb', None, '!', 'ccc', None, '!', 'ddd', '.', None, 'eee']
>>> sp[::3] # the result
['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc', 'ddd', 'eee']
>>> sp[1::3] # where matches `.`
['.', None, None, '.']
>>> sp[2::3] # where matches `!`
[None, '!', '!', None]
```

Comment: How can i remove `None` from the output